# Examination of idempotent elements of the Catalan monoid

Tags: semigroups

Let $\mathcal{C}_n$ be the Catalan monoid of self-maps, that is, $\alpha$ of $\{1\dots,n\}$ that are order-preserving ($\forall x,y$, $x\le y$ $\Rightarrow$ $\alpha(x)\le\alpha(y)$ and decreasing ($\forall x$, $\alpha(x)\le x$). For any semigroup $S$, all idempotent elements in $S$ is denoted by $E(S)$.

For any idempotent element  of $\mathcal{C}_n$, say $\epsilon$,
let $\mathcal{C}_n(\epsilon)=\{\alpha\in\mathcal{C}_n: \alpha^m=\epsilon, m\in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$. Let $T=\cup_{\epsilon\in E(T)}\mathcal{C}_n(\epsilon)$.

> - My question is when $T$ can be subsemigroup of $\mathcal{C}_n$?

It is clear that if $E(T)$ consist only one element, then $T$ is a subsemigroup of $\mathcal{C}_n$. But i need more general examination.

Comment: What is $x$ in the definition of $C_n(e)$?

Comment: By the way, what is $m$ in the definition of $C_n(e)$? Please revise your post. You should also adopt some homogeneous notation: $\alpha$ is a greek letter, but $e$ is a roman letter, which is quite disturbing.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin You are right. I edited it.